# Any Alternatives to NCommon?

Tags: c#, .net, domain-driven-design, ncommon

I like the way NCommon saves me from dealing with all the plumbing required to do DDD with NHibernate.

I like it so much that it I am seriously considering it to be part of my default architecture in new projects.

I'd like to ask if there are other DDD alternatives (aside from coding from scratch) to what NCommon does.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used it myself in production, just skimmed the source code, but there's an overlap with [S#arp Architecture](http://sharparchitecture.net/). In addition to the NHibernate basics, you also get ASP.NET MVC basics, since the goal is "building maintainable web applications".

Comment: I have done a little work on a side project with S#arp Architecture with the same view as yourself of using it as a core for an architecture.

I have found it to be excellent and saves a lot of time, I have hooked in DTOs for data transport and use AutoMapper for this again saving a lot of time and code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi. 

I'm curious. "Architectural foundation for building maintainable web applications with ASP.NET MVC" Does this mean that I can't use this in WebForms or Windows projects?